# How to Use OpenCV Wait Key With Chaquopy

Tags: android, opencv, chaquopy

I am attempting to use Chaquopy to port a computer vision application to android. When I try to run my script the following error occurs on the following line:

```
cv2.waitKey(100)
```

The error which prints to the embedded python console is:

```
java.chaquopy.CQPEnv.check_exception
com.chaquo.python.PyException: error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /home/smith/git/chaquo/python/server/pypi/packages/opencv-python/build/3.4.2.16/cp36-cp36m-android_15_armeabi_v7a/src/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:698: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvWaitKey'
```

I have installed openCV in the build gradle as follows:

```
        pip {
            install "opencv-python"
        }
```

Which is according to the Chaquopy documentation found here:
[Chaquopy openCV discussion](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/31)

Comment: Isn't the error message rather self-explanatory? You can't use any of the [highgui](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html) functionality with this build, as it wasn't compiled with any of the backends enabled.

Comment: Yes, this was more of a question related to the chaquopy package for Android, not all of the limitations are included in the documentation. Thank you though for the additional explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like OpenCV only has support for key events on desktop platforms, not mobile ones.  The same is probably true of all the other ["High-level GUI"](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/highgui.html) functions.

Anyway, unless your Android device actually has a keyboard, waiting for a keypress doesn't really make sense. You might be better off creating a simple Android UI like in the [Chaquopy demo app](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy), and interacting with the user that way.

Comment: Understood, thank you for pointing out the limitations of Chaquopy, I think we will go with a java native solution or a cloud solution instead. A bit too much troubleshooting with Chaquopy.